# Finding the largest subarray with equal number of 0's and 1's

Tags: arrays, algorithm

So, I have an array containing only 0's and 1's. I have to find out the largest subarray containing equal number of 0's and 1's. One can be a naive approach have complexity as `O(n^2)` where I take every element in outer loop and calculate possible subarrays in the inner loop and keep updating the maximum size, if found. Is there any other better approach (something like O(n)) that I can use? Thanks!

```
Input: arr[] = {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}
Output: 1 to 6 (Starting and Ending indexes of output subarray)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's an O(n)-time, O(n)-space algorithm. I'm not sure it's optimal, but it beats quadratic time.

The basic idea is the following. Suppose that you scan from the left of the array to the right recording, at each step, the difference between the number of 1s and the number of 0s. If you write these values out at each step, you'll get something like this:

```
  1,   0,   1,    0,    0,   0,   0
0,   1,   0,   1,    0,    -1,  -2,  -3
```

If you have a sub array with the same number of 0s and 1s, then the net difference of 0s and 1s at the start of the subarray will equal the net number after the subarray. Therefore, this problem can be reframed as trying to find two equal values in the auxiliary array that are equal and as far apart as possible.

The good news is that every entry in the array is between -n and +n, so you can make a 2n+1 element table and store in it the indices of the first and last time each number appears. From there, it's easy to find the longest range. Overall, this needs O(n) space and everything can be populated and searched in O(n) time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Right, this will do. Yup. Great thoughts. :)

Comment: what about the sequence of following:
`0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0`

Comment: That would give the array 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -3, -4, -3, -4, -5, -6. Either the range delimited by -3 or the range delimited by -4 would give you what you were looking for. Though perhaps I’m missing something?

Comment: @templatetypedef, thanks for sharing this! I've added an implementation based off your idea here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53900838/919858

Answer (score 5):

First convert your zeros to -1. Then you are looking for a maximum subarray of zero sum. An algorithm for this is described [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-if-there-is-a-subarray-with-0-sum/)

Comment: But then, it will be something finding all subarrays with sum as 0 and coming up with maximum length one. Finding a subarray itself has O(n) time complexity and then I will do it (in worst case, n times, I guess) making it O(n^2) again.

Comment: If you look up the link I gave you will see there is a O(n) answer there. But the other answer is more specific to this problem and better...

Comment: The algorithm in the link finds the first subarray, not the longest subarray. Also, it does not take for granted the binary nature of the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int equalNumber(int arr[]){

    int sum[] = new int[arr.length];
    sum[0] = arr[0] == 0? -1 : 1;
    for(int i=1; i < sum.length; i++){
        sum[i] = sum[i-1] + (arr[i] == 0? -1 : 1);
    }

    Map<Integer,Integer> pos = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    int maxLen = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(int s : sum){
        if(s == 0){
            maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, i+1);
        }
        if(pos.containsKey(s)){
            maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, i-pos.get(s));
        }else{
            pos.put(s, i);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return maxLen;
}
```

Comment: Could be improved if edited with some discussion about how it answers the question and about run complexity.

Comment: in above asked for if anyone have any better approach, i have this one so i shared it ..

Comment: copied from https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/25465/longest-continous-zero-sum-subarray/6#

Answer (score 1):

**What is the Solution ?**

So, In this solution, it would consider all subarrays and for each subarray, it'll count the total number of 0's and 1's present. If the subarray contains an equal number of both (0's and 1's) then update the largest array if required.
Time Complexity for this solution is O(n^3) as there are n^2 subarrays in array size of n, and it will take O(n) to find count 0's and 1's. Here, we can optimize the method to run O(n^2) by calculating the count of 0's and 1's within constant time.

**How can We Solve this?**

Here, We can use the map to solve it in linear time. Idea is to replace 0 with -1 and find out the largest subarray with the sum of 0.

So to find the Largest Subarray, create an empty map that will stores the first subarray's ending having a given sum. Then traverse the given array and maintain the sum in elements.

- If the sum is seen for 1st time then enter the sum with the index in the map.
- If the sum is seen before, there exists a subarray with a sum of 0, which ends at the current index, and update the largest subarray if the current subarray has more length.

```
class Solution {
    // Function to find the largest subarray having an equal number
    // of 0's and 1's
    public static void findLargestSubarray(int[] nums)
    {
        // create an empty `HashMap` to store the ending index of the first
        // subarray having some sum
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
 
        // insert (0, -1) pair into the set to handle the case when a
        // subarray with zero-sum starts from index 0
        map.put(0, -1);
 
        // `len` stores the maximum length of subarray with zero-sum
        int len = 0;
 
        // stores ending index of the largest subarray having zero-sum
        int end_index = -1;
 
        int sum = 0;
 
        // Traverse through the given array
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
        {
            // sum of elements so far (replace 0 with -1)
            sum += (nums[i] == 0)? -1: 1;
 
            // if the sum is seen before
            if (map.containsKey(sum))
            {
                // update length and ending index of largest subarray having zero-sum
                if (len < i - map.get(sum))
                {
                    len = i - map.get(sum);
                    end_index = i;
                }
            }
            // if the sum is seen for the first time, insert the sum with its
            // index into the map
            else {
                map.put(sum, i);
            }
        }
 
        // print the subarray if present
        if (end_index != -1)
        {
            System.out.println("[" + (end_index - len + 1) + ", " +
                                    end_index + "]");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No subarray exists");
        }
    }
```

Time Complexity : O(n) and requires O(n) extra space, where n is the size of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from @templatetypedef algorithm i wrote code in python, hope it can be helpful for someone.

```
def check_max_length(input_array):
    length = len(input_array)
    mapping_dict = {}
    max_length = 0
    for i in range(length):
        if input_array[i] not in mapping_dict.keys():
            mapping_dict[input_array[i]] = i
        else:
            max_length = max(max_length,i-mapping_dict[input_array[i]])
    return max_length

def find_max_substring_length(input_string):
    def_array = [0]
    zero_count = 0
    one_count = 0
    # difference between number of zeroes and ones
    def_zero_one = 0
    for i in range(len(input_string)):
        if input_string[i] == '1':
            one_count+=1
        else:
            zero_count+=1

        def_array.append(one_count-zero_count)
    max_substring = check_max_length(def_array)
return max_substring

input_string = '1000100'
substring_length = find_max_substring_length(input_string)
print(substring_length) // will give result as 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is closely related to @templatetypedef's answer.
However, rather than see it as a the difference between number of ones and zeros. I'm seeing at as a `tracker` of sorts that is incremented when a one is seen and decremented when a zero is seen .

Here's a tested solution.

```
 /**
 * given an array of 0's and 1's return the length of the maximal
 * subarray that has only 0's and 1's
 * O(n) solution inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/31201586/919858
 *
 * in           0    0    1    1
 * aux         0  -1   -2   -1   0
 * @param in
 * @return
 */
static int lenMaxSubArray(int[] in) {
    int maxLen = -1;
    int[] oneCount = new int[in.length + 1];
    oneCount[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
        if (in[i] == 1) {
            oneCount[i + 1] = oneCount[i] + 1;
        } else {
            oneCount[i + 1] = oneCount[i] - 1;
        }
    }

    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < oneCount.length; i++) {
        List<Integer> list = map.getOrDefault(oneCount[i], new ArrayList<>());
        list.add(i);
        map.put(oneCount[i], list);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < oneCount.length; i++) {
        List<Integer> list = map.get(oneCount[i]);
        if (list != null) {
            int start = list.get(0);
            int end = list.get(list.size() - 1);
            maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, end - start);
        }
    }

    return maxLen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxLen(int nums[], int n)
{   
    unordered_map<int, int> m;
    m[0] = -1;
    int ans = 0, cur = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cur += nums[i] ? 1 : -1;
        if (m.count(cur))
            ans = max(ans, i - m[cur]);
        else
            m[cur] = i;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS implementation of the @templatetypedef algorithm with a modification of using a map to help find the max length

```
function findMaxLen(a) {
// secondary array, initialized with the first element as 0
let b = [0]
let sum = 0

// populate the secondary array and update the sum as per the algorithm
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b[i + 1] = a[i] == 0 ? sum - 1 : sum + 1
    sum = b[i + 1]
}

// map of sum vs the first index of the secondary array with the sum value
let map = new Map()
let maxLen = 0

for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    if (map.has(b[i]))
        maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, i - map.get(b[i]))
    else
        map.set(b[i], i)
}

return maxLen
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int findMaxLength(vector<int>& nums) {
        int n=nums.size();
        if(n<=1) return 0;
        vector<int> arr(n,-1);
        arr[0]= (nums[0]==0)? -1:1 ;

        for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            arr[i] = arr[i-1] + ((nums[i]==0)? -1 : 1) ;
        }

        int sol=0;
        unordered_map<int,int> mp;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]==0) sol = i+1;
            else
            {
                if(mp.find(arr[i])==mp.end())
                {
                    mp[arr[i]]=i;
                }
                else
                {
                    sol=max(sol,i-mp[arr[i]]);
                }
            }
        }
        return sol;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hash map implementation in O(n) time.

```
int count=0, max_length=0;
        unordered_map<int,int> mp;
        mp[0] = -1;

        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++)
        {
            if(nums[i] == 0) count += -1;
            if(nums[i] == 1) count += 1;

            if(mp.find(count) != mp.end())
                max_length = max(max_length, i-mp[count]);
            else
                mp[count] = i;                        
        }

        return max_length;
```

Hope this code block helps.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm

We make use of a HashMap map to store the entries in the form of (index,count). We make an entry for a count in the map whenever the count is encountered first, and later on use the corresponding index to find the length of the largest subarray with equal no. of zeros and ones when the same count is encountered again.

```
public class Solution {

    public int findMaxLength(int[] nums) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(0, -1);
        int maxlen = 0, count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            count = count + (nums[i] == 1 ? 1 : -1);
            if (map.containsKey(count)) {
                maxlen = Math.max(maxlen, i - map.get(count));
            } else {
                map.put(count, i);
            }
        }
        return maxlen;
    }
}





Time complexity : O(n). The entire array is traversed only once.

Space complexity : O(n). Maximum size of the HashMap map will be n, if all the elements are either 1 or 0.
```